# Google Calendar API — htmlLink property of the Event does not work properly when logged in with multiple accounts

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I would like to display the link to the Calendar Event. I get the link from the Google Calendar API as part of the `Event` object — `htmlLink` property.

The problem happens when the user meets the following conditions:

- They are logged in via multiple Google accounts (say, Private and Work)
- The primary account does not match the one who has access to the Calendar in question

What happens next:

- When the mentioned user clicks the link, they are taken to the Calendar of their **primary account** instead of the **calendar that is associated with the event**. This naturally results in permissions error.
- When the user copies the URL, then goes to their calendar, then switches their account to the **secondary account** and **insert the URL manually**, then it works.

Do you guys know of a user-friendly way to mitigate this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out:

In API we get `htmlLink` like

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=[\w+]
```

Modify it into:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&eid=[\w+]
```

The new link leads different users to different pages:

- For users logged in, location is redirected into their own calendar page, and a popup inside the webpage appears to show event information.
- For clients not logged in with any Google account, there would be no redirections and a traditional page is shown.

For example: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&eid=OGxnZ2loODc5YWU0NzM5aGc1YWtkZmxsZzhfMjAyMjEwMjlUMDUzMDAwWiB0YWl3YW5oYW5kam9iQG0

---

And for those who do not use Google API but want a link to an individual event:
use `publish event` function in the event menu to get an URL with `eid`, and then modify the URL manually.

Comment: If there are multiple signed in accounts, google tries to load the primary one, so the link breaks unless you set which logged in account calendar to load. It's done by addeding `/u/<id>` after `calendar`, like so `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/1/event?eid=NGdvcDNyaGc3bGk5N...`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly same issue, however my app had access to user's current gmail id the user has used to login with.

so adding `authuser=<gmail_id>` in the url helped resolving this issue.

Example url:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/2024/2/12?eid=<event_id>&authuser=<gmail_id>
```